# Using $this when not in object context in

Tags: php

Не понимаю, почему не работает.
Вот что пишет, при попытке запроса

> Using $this when not in object context in

Вот сам запрос

```
$sql = "SELECT count(*) FROM `users`";
$query = db::select($sql, 'num');
```

Если кто объяснит - буду рад.

```
 class db{
    public $db = NULL;

    public function __construct(){
        if($this->db == NULL){
            $this->db = new PDO("mysql:host=localhost;dbname=saki", 'root', '');
        }
        else
            return $this->db;
    }
    public function __destruct(){
        $this->db = null;
    }

    public function query($sql){
        return $query = $this->db->query($sql);
    }


    public function select($sql, $type){
        $query = $this->db->query($sql);

        if($type == 'assoc')
            return $query->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

        elseif($type == 'obj')
            return $query->fetch(PDO::FETCH_OBJ);

        elseif($type == 'num')
            return $query->fetch(PDO::FETCH_BOTH);

    }
    public function insert($sql, $arr){
        $add = $this->db->prepare($query);
        $add->execute($arr);
    }
}
```

**UPD:** Забыл добавить, ошибка указывает на строку 29, в которой:

```
$query = $this->db->query($sql);
```

Comment: Забыл добавить, в 29 строке пишет .
$query = $this->db->query($sql);

Comment: пожалуйста, внесите уточнения в сам вопрос, нажав [edit].

Comment: @user190134, Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ на вопрос, отметьте его как "верный".

Comment: Ищу ищу, не вижу как...

Comment: @user190134, галочка, в левой части ответа...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вместо этого класса пишешь

```
$opt = array(
    PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE            => PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION,
    PDO::ATTR_DEFAULT_FETCH_MODE => PDO::FETCH_ASSOC
);
$pdo = new PDO("mysql:host=localhost;dbname=saki", 'root', '', $opt);

function pdo($sql, $data=[]) 
{
    global $pdo;
    $stmt = $pdo->prepare($sql);
    $stmt->execute($data);
    return $stmt;
}
```

Пока не изучишь ООП, этого будет более чем достаточно для выполнения любых запросов, эта функция заменит тебе и метод insert(), и select(), и все какие ты еще только собираешься написать. Причём для запросов SELECT можно будет получить любое количество строк, а не одну, как у тебя.

Не говоря уже о том, что твой код сократится с **трех** строчек до одной:

```
$num = pdo("SELECT count(*) FROM `users`")->fetchColumn();
```

ЗЫ. PDO умеет *гораздо* больше, чем ты думаешь. И перед тем, как писать свой враппер на его основе, его надо хорошенько изучить. Тогда окажется, что писать-то особо и нечего.

Если всё же хочешь статическую запускалку для PDO, то вот готовая, http://phpfaq.ru/pdo_wrapper

Обрати внимание, что в таком классе обязателно должен быть либо на 100% продублирован функционал PDO, либо должен быть обеспечен доступ к объекту $pdo. Чтобы потом не спрашивать, как узнать last insert id или начать транзакцию.

Answer (score 1):

Вот здесь:

```
$query = db::select($sql, 'num');
```

вы пытаетесь используете обычный метод класса `db` как статический. А в контексте статического метода, переменная `$this` не доступна, о чем вам и сообщает PHP.

Answer (score 1):

В объекте метод `select` указан не статическим, а вызывается как статический.

> Так как статические методы вызываются без создания экземпляра класса, то псевдо-переменная **$this** не доступна внутри метода, объявленного статическим.
>   ...
>   При попытке вызова нестатических методов статически выводится предупреждение уровня **E_STRICT**.

(с) http://php.net/manual/ru/language.oop5.static.php