# An exception occurred: Using $this when not in object context in /Listener/Template.php on line 93

Tags: php

```
public static function templateHook($hookName, &$contents, array $hookParams, XenForo_Template_Abstract $template)
    {
        $chatboxModel  = XenForo_Model::create('XenSupport_Chatbox_Model_Messages');

        if ($hookName == 'chatbox_widget' && $chatboxModel->canViewChatbox())
        {
            $securityModel = XenForo_Model::create('XenSupport_Chatbox_Model_Security');
            $chatboxModel  = XenForo_Model::create('XenSupport_Chatbox_Model_Messages');
            $banningModel  = XenForo_Model::create('XenSupport_Chatbox_Model_Banning');
            $visitor       = XenForo_Visitor::getInstance();

            $ban = $banningModel->getBannedUserById($visitor['user_id']);
            if ($ban) // check if user is banned from chatbox
            {
                $templateParams = $hookParams + array('ban' => $ban) + $template->getParams();
                $result         = $template->create('chatbox_banned_message', $templateParams)->render();
                $contents      .= $result;
                return; // user banned, no need to display the chatbox in widget
            }

            $formatter    = XenForo_BbCode_Formatter_Base::create('Base', array('view' => $this));
            $bbCodeParser = XenForo_BbCode_Parser::create($formatter);
            $notice       = new XenForo_BbCode_TextWrapper(XenForo_Application::get('options')->chatbox_notice, $bbCodeParser);

            $userIdKey = $securityModel->createEncryption(array('user_id' => $visitor['user_id']));

            $params = array(
                'userIdKey'          => $userIdKey,
                'canEditNotice'      => $chatboxModel->canEditNotice(),
                'canPostMessage'     => $chatboxModel->canPostMessages(),
                'canViewChatbox'     => $chatboxModel->canViewChatbox(),
                'canUseMessageColor' => $chatboxModel->canUseMessageColor(),
                'notice'             => $notice,
                'widget'             => true,
                'height'             => $hookParams['height']
            );

            $templateParams = $hookParams + $params + $template->getParams();

            $result = $template->create('chatbox_index', $templateParams)->render();
            $contents .= $result;
        }
    }
}
```

(93 строка)

```
$formatter    = XenForo_BbCode_Formatter_Base::create('Base', array('view' => $this));
$bbCodeParser = XenForo_BbCode_Parser::create($formatter);
$notice       = new XenForo_BbCode_TextWrapper(XenForo_Application::get('options')->chatbox_notice, $bbCodeParser);
```

Как исправить ошибочку, помогите пожалуйста)

Comment: В статических методах `$this` нет

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Using $this when not in object context in](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/449287/using-this-when-not-in-object-context-in)